# PostgreSQL database columns and jobs missing after Windows Update

Tags: php, postgresql, windows-update

I only noticed it after the last Windows 10 update. After I looked into my database using PgAdmin I noticed columns missing.
I can't see OID column any more. When I select all columns from my **users** and **movies** table as you can see:

[image: NO OID VISIBLE]

But if I select to view all data it exists

[image: Now it is visible]

Also all of my jobs are now gone. Also users are missing from my database but they are still there I know that by the fact that I set up a trigger to check if a email already exists. I tried adding new user and it says "email exists" so that means they are still somewhere.

Now my PHP won't work because it says OID does not exist. But how can that be, since it is clearly visible? And to add to that some of my triggers are missing too. I didn't want to reinstall anything because I'm afraid that I'd lose even more data.

I don't know what's happening? It happened the other day but I restarted my PC and it showed up again. Now restart won't help.

Comment: What are *jobs* in PostgreSQL? Are you using plain PostgreSQL or some fork? Are you using pgAgent? You should include that information in your question, along with version numbers for PostgreSQL and pgAdmin III. Also, remove the `oid` tag as that is a different product. If a restart fixed the problem at some point, maybe your data are fine and pgAdmin III is misconfigured.

Comment: Im using postgresql 9.5 with pgadmin 3 v1.22.0. RC 1 and pgagent (jobs). It all worked fine until windows updated now it's all like this... I have tried to restart it several times but with no luck. I have no idea what could have gone wrong